# OnetoOneField Django query

Tags: python, django, templates, one-to-one

so I have this two models:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    patientID = models.CharField(max_length=200 , default='Enter PatientID')
    age = models.IntegerField(default='-')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=Gender_Choice, default='UNDEFINED')

class RiskFactor(models.Model):
    patient = models.OneToOneField(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hypertension = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    diabetes = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    PAVK = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    nicotin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

So I've changed from ForeignKey to OnetoOneField because of reasons. So with the ForeignKey everything was easypeasy and I can show the data of the RiskFactor model in my Patient detail template. Now I have problems to change the query. I just don't know how to change this:

```html
<ul>
  {% for rfac in patient.riskfactor_set.all %}
   <li>Hypertension: {{ rfac.hypertension }}<br/>
      Diabetes: {{ rfac.diabetes }}<br/>
      PAVK: {{ rfac.PAVK }}<br/>
      Nicotin: {{ rfac.nicotin }}<br/>
   </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

into sth that shows the riskfactor data from the patient with a OneToOneRel.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would add `related_name="risk_factor"` to your OneToOneField declaration, just to make it more clear how to reference the associated RiskFactor. From there, you can reference it like any other property of `patient` - it no longer is a list, but a single object. Like so below

```
<ul>
  {% with patient.risk_factor as rfac %}
    <li>Hypertension: {{ rfac.hypertension }}<br/>
      Diabetes: {{ rfac.diabetes }}<br/>
      PAVK: {{ rfac.PAVK }}<br/>
      Nicotin: {{ rfac.nicotin }}<br/>
    </li>
  {% endwidth %}
</ul>
```

You can do without the `with` statement, but it makes it easiest to convert your code, plus then you would have to put `patient.risk_factor.` before every property you want, so might as well save it to `rfac`.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to query a set of a one to one relationship which isn't possible. Since every Patient can only have 1 RiskFactor.

Why don't you get the risk factors based on the patient and pass it into the template like this:

```
patient_risk = RiskFactor.objects.get(patient=patient)

ctx = {
    'rfac': patient_risk
}
```

Then in your template you could access the risks for that particular patients.

```
<ul>
   <li>Hypertension: {{ rfac.hypertension }}<br/>
      Diabetes: {{ rfac.diabetes }}<br/>
      PAVK: {{ rfac.PAVK }}<br/>
      Nicotin: {{ rfac.nicotin }}<br/>
   </li>
</ul>
```

You can also query all of the RiskFactors models and access the patient via `RiskFactor.patient` if you want to loop over all patients who have RiskFactors.

```
all_risk_factors = RiskFactor.objects.all()

ctx = {
    'risk_factors': all_risk_factors
}

<ul>
  {% for risk in risk_factors %}
   <li><strong>Patient ID: risk.patient.patientID</strong></li>
   <li>Hypertension: {{ risk.hypertension }}<br/>
      Diabetes: {{ risk.diabetes }}<br/>
      PAVK: {{ risk.PAVK }}<br/>
      Nicotin: {{ risk.nicotin }}<br/>
   </li>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Your way seems legit to me but I am just totally new to Django so I have no clue where do you put you definition of patient_risk and ctx in. Is it in the views?

Comment: In you template you have access to the `patient`, that's how you're able to do `patient.riskfactor'. That's called a context, it's variables you've passed into the template to render.  You can read more about Django template context on their [template docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/).